Trying desperately to get iframe to work on wordpress template
So the front page of the site is setup within the template Macclesfield-Remapping.co.uk, down near the bottom it say 0% Finance available, the space above is where i want the iframe to sit, but i have tried everything and still no joy! What am i doing wrong anyone?
div#iframe {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    left: 40px;
    bottom: 25px;
    min-width: 200px;
    width: 40%;
    background: black;
}

div#iframe iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
    <div class="single-top">
        <div class="section-title">
            <h2 class="title inner-area-title">
                Macclesfield Mobile Remapping Service
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="iframe">
            <iframe frameborder="0" id="remap-calculator" src="https://mychiptuningfiles.com/en/iframe/token/snXcz3osnmF0GJQtXWxDj7us9jud5ZRF1WMBYKyk" title="Remap Calculator" loading="lazy" class="iframe" scrolling="auto" onload="" allowtransparency="false" allowfullscreen style="width:100%; max-width:100%; height:320px"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="skill-border"></div>
        <div class="inner-area-percent">
            0%
        </div>
        <div class="inner-area-percenttext">
                Free Finance On Remapping
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

I have tried various ways and means but nothing seems to make it show
